# How to make sure that random.choice() doesn't pick the same item twice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a quiz. That means I have to generate random questions for a list, but I need to make sure that questions aren't repeated.  I am using Python 3.1.4, but I dont know how to make sure it checks if the string hasn't already been generated. The piece of code that I am using to generate the string is:

```
generated_question = random.choice(question_list)
```

Comment: Simply use random.shuffle() and then consume the list with list.pop().

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `choice`, consider using `shuffle` and `.pop`:

```
question_order = question_list[:] # make a copy of the input list
random.shuffle (question_order)
for i in range(5):
    print(question_order.pop())
```

This will print out five questions (assuming you have at least that many in he list) without duplicates.

Comment: Or create a copy and `shuffle` in one go: `question_order = random.sample(question_list, len(question_list))` (although I suspect a shallow copy and shuffle will be faster due to the way shuffle works)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use the sample function instates of choices
random.sample("your list or any thing name" , k = "count of random object that you want")
easily you have to do this :

```
import random
import string
str_list = string.ascii_lowercase
print(random.sample(str_list, 5))
```

and output will be :

```
['l', 'o', 'r', 'p', 'm']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a copy of your List and remove each questions once it's asked from that copy:

```
question_list_2 = question_list
while len(question_list_2) > 0: #use all questions
    generated_question = random.choice(question_list_2)
    print(generated_question)
    question_list_2.remove(generated_question)
```

This will print all questions and every question will be printed only once.

Comment: `.remove` in a loop is going to be rather slow (O(n^2)).

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but asymptotically mensuring runtime is something that starts becoming interesting at huge values for n and I didn't think the OP was going to aks a million questions :) But in theory you're right.

Comment: @nneonneo: performance is irrelevant when the list is so tiny. This is especially true in UI code where you only need to be as fast as the user's perception (ie: on the order of 100's of milliseconds)

Comment: @BryanOakley: learning to do things using faster approaches is good practice in general. If it costs you nothing more to use a faster approach, why go for slower?

Comment: @TuxTorvalds: also, FYI, your answer does not correctly make a copy of the list.

Comment: @nneonneo: true, but learning to be pragmatic is equally important. I wasn't criticizing you, I was just offering an alternate viewpoint.